# Jquery sidebar not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer

Could anyone eplain to me, why this isn't working in IE?
It's fading perfectly into each image in other browsers, but when executed in IE, it only shows the last image(image 5) and stays that way.
And maybe come up with a possible solution ? I am very new to jquery
JS:

```
var rotationTime = 3000;
var fadeTimer = 500;
var zStart = 25;

var totalBanners;
var currentImage = 1;

$(document).ready(function(){
    totalBanners = $('#fade-slider > div').length;
    for(i=1;i<=totalBanners;i++){
        $('#img-' + i).css('z-index', '' + (zStart-i) + '');
    }
    $(document).everyTime(rotationTime,  'imagefader', function(){          
        if(currentImage < totalBanners){
            $('#img-' + currentImage).animate({opacity: 0}, fadeTimer);
            currentImage += 1;
        }
        else{
            currentImage = 1;
            $('#img-' + currentImage).animate({opacity: 1}, fadeTimer, 'linear', function(){
                for(i=1;i<=totalBanners;i++){
                    $('#img-' + i).animate({opacity: 1}, 0);
                }
            });         
        }       
    }, 0);
});
```

CSS:

```
@charset "UTF-8";
    #fade-slider {
      width:570px;
      height:207px;
      overflow:hidden;
      margin:0px;
      padding:0px;
      position:relative;
    }

    .position-zero {
        position:absolute;
        top:0px;
        left:0px;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="fade-slider">
                        <div id="img-1" class="position-zero"><a href="#"><img src="images/slider/image-1.jpg" alt="Image1" /></a></div>
                        <div id="img-2" class="position-zero"><a href="#"><img src="images/slider/image-2.jpg" alt="Image2" /></a></div>  
                        <div id="img-3" class="position-zero"><a href="#"><img src="images/slider/image-3.jpg" alt="Image3" /></a></div>    
                        <div id="img-4" class="position-zero"><a href="#"><img src="images/slider/image-4.jpg" alt="Image4" /></a></div>     
                        <div id="img-5" class="position-zero"><a href="#"><img src="images/slider/image-5.jpg" alt="Image5" /></a></div>       
                    </div>
```

Comment: Which version of Internet Explorer are you using?

Comment: What does the JS console in IE tell you? (Double click the status bar at the bottom of IE) If there are any errors, it will give a pop up box. If no box appears, then you can (normally) rule out JS problems.

Comment: Hello Brant.
It doesn't show any errors.. But i don't see how this can't be a JS problem

Comment: is your IE running in Compatibility or Quirks mode? In the F12 tools, make sure it's running in IE9 Standards mode

Comment: The script is running fine, now after accepting active x objects in IE. Thanks alot everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing

```
$('#img-' + i).css('z-index', '' + (zStart-i) + '');
```

to

```
$('#img-' + i).css({'z-index':(zStart-i)});
```

or

```
$('#img-' + i).css('z-index', (zStart-i));
```

I'm not going to lay claim that it will work. But I think it could be just the way IE is interpreting things, I think it may be being interpreted as a string rather than an INT value and in that, not rendering it correctly. But again not saying that is the issue exactly, just something about that line doesn't sit right in my head, and without testing it (being on a Mac currently and not having IE) I can't be sure.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time Chris.
It wasnt the issue though. The script is running fine, now after accepting active x objects in IE. Thanks alot everyone